# PHP SQL $stmt->fetch() push array into another array

Tags: php, sql

I have some problems with $stmt->fetch()

I have a variable called $row which consists of $row['id'] and $row['name'].
In the $stmt->fetch() loop I want to append the row to a $result array.
But if print the $result array it only consists out of the last row.

Here is my code:

```
function queryResult($sql, $params, $columNames) {

    $result = [];
    $row = [];
    $bindVars = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($columNames); $i++) {
        $bindVars[] = &$row[$columNames[$i]];
    }

    $stmt = $this->query($sql, $params);
    call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_result'], $bindVars);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
        echo '<br>';
        array_push($result, $row);
        print_r($result);
        echo '<br><br>';
    }

    return $result;

}
```

And this is the result:

```
Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Test2 ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Test2 ) ) 

Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Test3 ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Test3 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Test3 ) )
```

Comment: Can you paste you full code

Comment: I have updated it with the whole function.

Comment: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())` maybe???

Answer (score 0):

In line 14 I think `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))` should be used.

Comment: But the problem is not that the row variables are not right. I just don't get them together in an array.